# Superinsulator infinite voltage

Tags: electrical-resistance, voltage, phase-transition, superconductivity, cryogenics

Everybody knows about superconductivity, at cryogenic temperatures conductor resistance drops to zero for direct current. There is lesser known related phenomena called superinsulator where material gains infinite resistance.

Does it really block infinite high voltage? That seems to me too extreme to be true. Even the strongest insulators like telfon or fused quartz eventually breakdown under high voltage, so can these superinsulators really block infinite voltage?

Answer (score 3):

To quote [Wikipedia article on superinsulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superinsulator):

> The superinsulating state is the exact dual to the superconducting state and can be destroyed by increasing the temperature and applying an external magnetic field and voltage.

The reason for calling them *superinsulators* is then not because it cannot conduct at infinitely high voltage. Rather the definition of *insulator* here is as the material in which the excitations are localized, as opposed to a *metal* - a material where the excitations are extended. The two are dual, in the sense that they represent two thermodynamic phases separated by [the metal-insulator transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal%E2%80%93insulator_transition). While in normal state the conducting excitations are electrons (more precisely the Landau quasiparticles), in the superconducting state these are *Cooper pairs*. It is thus natural to add prefix *super-* to an insulating material whose excitations are *Cooper pairs*.

Comment: What do you mean localized and extended excitations? You mean that voltage makes electrons move in the whole piece of metal while in superinsulator it only moves electrons in some small localized spot? Like those vortices?

Comment: @Soliton in metal excitation wave functions are (similar to) plane waves, extending through the whole crystal, whereas in an insulator they are bound states.